# Adding new column with the header containing date at the beginning of CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was looking on Stackoverflow for this thing but I didn't find exactly what I wanted. I would like to open csv file on Python and add new column with header "Date" and until end of the file add today's date. How can I do it? I was trying to do it with pandas but I only know how to append to the end.

I was trying to do this that way with package csv:

```py
x=open(outfile_name1)
y=csv.reader(x)
z=[]
for row in y:
    z.append(['0'] + row)
```

Instead of ['0'] I wanted to put today's date. Can I then convert this list to csv with pandas or something? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Read the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

Comment: why there is need for temporary list? Can't one just open file for reading and another for writing, read by row and write row with date prepended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("my.csv")
df.insert(0, 'Date', datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
df.to_csv("my_withDate.csv", index=False)
```

PS: [Read the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df['Date'] = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df.to_csv("new_file.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Will it be added at the begininng of the file? ;)

Comment: It will create a new column "Date" having today's date in every row. The length of the column will be equal to the existing number of  rows in csv file.

Comment: You will have to save the new dataframe to a csv file. I added that line now.

Comment: This does not add the column to the start of file!

Comment: Do this: df = df[['a', 'b', 'c']] to rearrange them to your preference.

Comment: It sounds very interesting. However, I have a lot of columns in this file. Is there a way to move this new column at the beginning faster without listing all other columns?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I undestand ultimate goal is to write data to csv. One option to do that is to open first file for reading data, second for writing data then write header row into new file prepending it with column name 'Date,' and then iterate over data rows prepending them with date (requires 3.6 <= Python as uses f-strings):

```
import datetime

with open('columns.csv', 'r') as out, open('out.csv', 'w') as into:
    headers = 'Date,' + next(out)
    print(headers, end='', file=into)
    for row in out:
        print(f'{datetime.datetime.today().date()}, {row}', end='', file=into)
```